# Pushing data to UISplitViewController's master and detail view controller swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to send my branches array to UISplitViewControllers' children.
But I am having my array count zero from childviewcontroller.
Any kind of help highly appreciated.

Thanks.

LoginVC -> SplitVC -> NavigationC -> BranchesTableVC

Following code is from my LoginVC

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toSplitVC") {
        if let splitViewController: BTSplitViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? BTSplitViewController {
            let masterViewController = (splitViewController.splitViewController?.viewControllers[0] as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? BTBranchTableViewController
            masterViewController?.branches = self.branches
        }

    }
}
```

And this is the code at BTBranchTableViewController

```
var branches:NSArray = []

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    print("branches count \(self.branches.count)")
}
```

Result : branches count 0

No Error Message

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem by adding following code to splitviewcontroller

```
let branchListViewController = (self.viewControllers[0] as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? BTBranchTableViewController

branchListViewController?.branches = self.branches
```